# WinJS URL field, '.com' key issue

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs, windows-8.1

We have a WinJS application that uses an input of type URL to enforce the correct virtual keyboard to pop up upon focus entering the field.  This includes the ".com" shortcut key found between the '/' key and the left arrow on the virtual keyboard.

Anytime we press this key, WinJS seems to be interpretting it as "mmmm" rather than ".com" as it's supposed to.

It may be relevant that this field is inside of a WinJS Flyout control, but I am still investigating.

Has anyone else run into this or found a workaround?  Thanks!

Comment: Just tried in a simple demo what you're seeing and `.com` shows up when the key is presed, not "mmmm". Can you provide any further details? Does it happen in the emulator and actual devices?

Comment: The same thing happens on our 1st Gen Surface RT, a Surface 2 and in the simulator under "Basic Touch" mode.

Comment: Hmm. I created a flyout control in a new Win8.1 WinJS app triggered from the settings charm, with a URL field, and it behaves correctly. I didn't try it on my Surface, but in the emulator it works correctly.

Comment: Could you add a `keydown` handler to the input box and output the `evt.char` for each key pressed? The `.com` button just causes the individual keys to be pressed, `.`, `c`, `o`, `m`, so you should see that.

Comment: We have created a test harness as well and were unable to reproduce.  We also added the "keypress" handler in the main application and we are, as expected, getting 4 `m` keypress events.  Really weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so it's a VERY odd issue, but we have it isolated.  The issue is the WinJS SearchBox's `focusOnKeyboardInput` property being set to true interfering somehow.  After reading through the [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301948.aspx) on this property, I'm not sure why one would ever set it to true.

```
<body>
    <input type="url" id="url1" />

    <!-- change focusOnKeyboardInput to 'false' and the issue goes away -->
    <div id="searchBuilderSearchBox"
         style="display: none"
         data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SearchBox"
         data-win-options="{
                chooseSuggestionOnEnter: false,
                focusOnKeyboardInput : true, 
                placeholderText: 'keywords',
                searchHistoryContext: 'search',
                searchHistoryDisabled: false }">
    </div>
</body>
```